# google app engine cron job backend

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, backend

I configured my cron.xml and backends.xml to be run on google app engine as following :

**cron.xml**

```
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/_ah/start</url>
        <schedule>every 5 minutes</schedule>
        <target>updatebackend</target>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

**backends.xml**

```
<backends>
    <backend name="updatebackend">
        <class>B1</class>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
            <public>false</public>
        </options>
    </backend>
</backends>
```

Then on my web.xml file I wrote like following :

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.UpdateBackendServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/start</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>mybackend</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/start</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

But when I deploy and run it on the google app engine, it always run twice. And my questions are :

1. How can I make another url-pattern besides /_ah/start?
2. How can I make it only run one time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot use `/_ah/start` as a handler for your requests - it is reserved for the purpose of starting a backend instance. You should use a different handler. For example:

```
<url>/update</url>
<url-pattern>/update</url-pattern>
```

Now, when you call `/update`, App Engine will either use an existing backend instance, or it will automatically issue `/_ah/start` to start a new instance. You don't need to call `/_ah/start` yourself, unless you want to start your instance before any other request is sent to it.

Comment: Hi Andrei,
Thanks for your answer. But if I did that, it will gave me this error :
/_ah/start
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet.getUserId(AbstractAppEngineAuthorizationCodeServlet.java:92)

Comment: I think the problem is I haven't make the servlet that point to the /_ah/start. After that been made, it will start the backend everytime I called the other servlet that supposed to be run on the backend.

Comment: can you share some sample to start java method from cron. I have no backend exp and need to code my GCE update method.

Comment: Cron job makes a standard HTTP.GET call to the handler that you specify. You simply need to process this call.